# How to Connect to MongoDB running on localhost from Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, minikube

I am learning about Kubernetes am trying move from docker-compose to use Kubernetes but having problem with connecting to MongoDB running on localhost.

I don't have any problems connecting using following docker-compose.yaml by using `'network_mode: "host"'`

```
//docker-compose.yaml
    version: '3'
    services:

      eureka:
        image: sage-eureka
        ports:
          - "8080:8080"
        network_mode: "host"
```

But I'm having issues in Kubernetes. I used [Kompose](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-docker-compose-workflow-to-kubernetes) to convert the docker-compose.

```
//application.properties
    spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost (tried adding mongo instead of localhost when used ExternalName and ClusterIP)
    spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
    spring.data.mongodb.database=MyMongo

// eureka-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: eureka
  name: eureka
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "8080"
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: "27017"
    port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: eureka
status:
  loadBalancer: {}

//eureka-deployment.yaml

 apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert
        kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: eureka
      name: eureka
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          io.kompose.service: eureka
      strategy: {}
      template:
        metadata:
          annotations:
            kompose.cmd: kompose convert
            kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
          creationTimestamp: null
          labels:
            io.kompose.service: eureka
        spec:
          hostNetwork: true
          dnsPolicy: Default
          containers:
          - args:
            - --spring.profiles.active=local
            image: sage-eureka
            imagePullPolicy: Never
            name: sageeureka
            ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
            - containerPort: 27017
            resources: {}
          restartPolicy: Always
          serviceAccountName: ""
          volumes: null
    status: {}
```

I'm also getting  on external ip address when I've added type to LoadBalencer and I've also tried creating Service type ExternalName and NodePort for Mongo as shown in [Kubernetes best practices: mapping external services](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services):

```
eureka       ClusterIP      10.102.22.91   <none>                 8080/TCP,27017/TCP   45h
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1      <none>                 443/TCP              4d2h
mongo        ExternalName   <none>         host.docker.internal   <none>               45h
```

I've referred to similar posts here but I don't know exactly what needs to be done and following these post are also not working for me as I don't know what I'm doing wrong:

- [com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket(MongoDB, Docker)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45742999/com-mongodb-mongosocketopenexception-exception-opening-socketmongodb-docker)
- [During local development with Kubernetes/minikube, how should I connect to postgres database running on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49289009/during-local-development-with-kubernetes-minikube-how-should-i-connect-to-postg)

I also tried creating the mongo-serivce as in 2nd post like this:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: host.docker.internal
```

Please Help!. Thank you.

Comment: Am I right that you are trying to get it up and running on GKE (assuming from tag) and what is the ultimate goal? To have it accessible from outside or just locally

Comment: @Nick. Currently i'm running on Minikube locally to test. For production environment will be using Mongo Atlas. So I need to be able to connect to the mongo IP from all of my services.

Answer (score 5):

Similar solution to [Connect to local database from inside minikube cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952240/connect-to-local-database-from-inside-minikube-cluster/67093139#67093139)

The issue is `host.minikube.internal` (not `host.docker.internal` -- this one is for kubernetes host at docker desktop) is not visible at kubernetes container somehow. See this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/8439). It is only visible at minikube ssh instance.

So it needs a workaround to attach this host to containers inside k8s.

Or just hard code the ip address in k8s container as the host. Find ip address from command `minikube ssh 'grep host.minikube.internal /etc/hosts | cut -f1'`.

For example, if the ip is `192.168.65.2`. Then use this ip as service host in k8s container, instead of `127.0.0.1/localhost`.

Comment: Feb 2024, you can mention the host name as `host.minikube.internal` instead of the exact IP address.

Answer (score 1):

**How to connect from Host to Pod in Minikube**

If the issue is that you can't access your Pods (via the `service`) on Minikube.

Let's check your `Service` first.

```
$ kubectl get service eureka
NAME     TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)          AGE
eureka   LoadBalancer   10.104.196.32   <pending>      8080:30167/TCP   25m
```

Note that, when running Minikube, a `LoadBalancer` service won’t acquire an external IP address.

Locally, Minikube doesn’t integrate with another service to run external load balancers.

But in most other environments, when you use a Kubernetes `LoadBalancer`, it will provision a load balancer external to your cluster, for example an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) in AWS, or a Cloud Load Balancer in GKE.

Because Minikube doesn’t integrate with a separate local load balancer, you have to ask Minikube to simulate the connection using minikube service:

`$ minikube service eureka`

That will provide you with the Minikube’s IP address and the port number Minikube routes to 'eureka', so and you can copy and paste that into a browser/other app to test the app.

Additional info can be found in [Minikube's documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/#quickstart):

> To access the hello-minikube Deployment, expose it as a Service:
>
> `kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube --type=NodePort --port=8080`
>
> Get the URL of the exposed Service to view the Service details:
>
> minikube service hello-minikube --url

**EDIT**

**How to connect from Pod to `localhost` on Minikube.Host**

> don't have any problems connecting using following docker-compose.yaml by using 'network_mode: "host"'

True.

If you use the `host` network mode for a container, that container’s network stack is not isolated from the Docker host (the container shares the host’s networking namespace), and the container does not get its own IP-address allocated. So if you run a container which binds to port 80 and you use `host` networking, the container’s application is available on port 80 on the host’s IP address.

Since minikube runs everything *from within a VM*, networking can get [fairly complicated](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/networking/)

Once Minikube is running and it’s network has been established, you should be able to visit your localhost server on both `127.0.0.1` and `192.168.99.1` (If not, subsequent steps will not work). If successful, this means that the Minikube VM can access your host machine’s localhost on `192.168.99.1` (`127.0.0.1` from Minikube would still be a Minicube's `localhost`)

That is why in this very case instead of `localhost` your app shall connect to `192.168.99.1`.

> ```
> kind: Service
> apiVersion: v1
> metadata:
>   name: mongo
> spec:
>   type: ExternalName
>   externalName: host.docker.internal
> ```

Please make sure that `host.docker.internal` is resolved to the IP address of Host machine.

Additionally you can edit `/etc/hosts` of Minikube and add any domain name for that IP, so you'll be able connecting to it.

Hope that explains how to access your app from outside and access specifically "`localhost`" when using Minikube.

Comment: Actually, the main issue is that I can't access MongoDB running on localhost from a spring service running in pod due to which pod fails to start with MondoDB Connection refused (MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket). I've edited my question and added some more changes. Also, thank you so much for reply.

Comment: Thank you @Sujal, l'll adjust my answer then

Comment: @Sujal, what is the Host OS? and what driver you are running? Is it VirtualBox? In case it's a VirtualBox, what is the Virtualbox adapter type?  is it a  NAT ?  I'm asking that because it looks like your App tries establishing connection to a _localhost_ (which is unreachable from Pod with current settings).

Comment: Minikube v1.9.0 on Ubuntu 18.04, Using the docker driver based on existing profile as displayed in minikube start. I'm not sure how to check the adapter type.

Comment: @Sujal , I've updated my answer. Basically either your app has to connect to `192.168.99.1` or you need adjusting `/etc/hosts` on minikube for `externalName: host.docker.internal` . I've tested that with Win+MySQL+minikube machine and mysql-client-pod