# Kubernetes Pod can't connect to local postgres server with Hasura image

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, hasura

I'm following [this tutorial](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/deployment/kubernetes/index.html#step-1-get-the-kubernetes-deployment-and-service-files) to connect a hasura kubernetes pod to my local postgres server.

When I create the deployment, the pod's container fails to connect to postgres (CrashLoopBackOff and keeps retrying), but doesn't give any reason why. Here are the logs:

```
{"type":"pg-client","timestamp":"2020-05-03T06:22:21.648+0000","level":"warn","detail":{"message":"postgres connection failed, retrying(0)."}}
```

My deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: hasura
    hasuraService: custom
  name: hasura
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hasura
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: hasura
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: hasura/graphql-engine:v1.2.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: hasura
        env:
        - name: HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL
          value: postgres://USER:@localhost:5432/my_db
        - name: HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE
          value: "true"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
```

I'm using `postgres://USER:@localhost:5432/MY_DB` as the postgres url - is "localhost" the correct address here?

I verified that the above postgres url works when I try (no password):

```
> psql postgres://USER:@localhost:5432/my_db
psql (12.2)
Type "help" for help.

> my_db=#
```

How else can I troubleshoot it? The logs aren't very helpful...

Comment: Can you explain your setup a bit?  Do you run your k8s cluster on Minikube?

Comment: Hi @Nick, yes, running locally on minikube.

Answer (score 1):

If I got you correctly, the issue is that the Pod (from  "inside" the Minikube ) can not access Postgres installed on Host machine (the one that runs Minikube itself) via `localhost`.

If that is the case, please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60882006/how-to-connect-to-mongodb-running-on-localhost-from-minikube/60986502#60986502) .

> ... Minikube VM can access your host machine’s localhost on 192.168.99.1 (127.0.0.1 from Minikube would still be a Minicube's localhost).

Technically, for the Pod the `localhost` is Pod itself. The Host machine and Minikube are connected via bridge. You can find out exact ip addresses and routes with the `infconfig` and `route -n` on your Minikube Host.