# Unable to connect: Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, minikube, debezium, strimzi

I am trying to follow the tutorial [Deploying Debezium using the new KafkaConnector resource](https://strimzi.io/blog/2020/01/27/deploying-debezium-with-kafkaconnector-resource/).
Based on the tutorial, I am also using minikube but with docker driver. Basically just follow exactly step by step.

However, for the step "Create the connector", after creating the connector by

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl -n kafka apply -f -
apiVersion: "kafka.strimzi.io/v1alpha1"
kind: "KafkaConnector"
metadata:
  name: "inventory-connector"
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: my-connect-cluster
spec:
  class: io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector
  tasksMax: 1
  config:
    database.hostname: 192.168.99.1
    database.port: "3306"
    database.user: "${file:/opt/kafka/external-configuration/connector-config/debezium-mysql-credentials.properties:mysql_username}"
    database.password: "${file:/opt/kafka/external-configuration/connector-config/debezium-mysql-credentials.properties:mysql_password}"
    database.server.id: "184054"
    database.server.name: "dbserver1"
    database.whitelist: "inventory"
    database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers: "my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092"
    database.history.kafka.topic: "schema-changes.inventory"
    include.schema.changes: "true" 
EOF
```

and check by

```
kubectl -n kafka get kctr inventory-connector -o yaml
```

I got error

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1alpha1
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"kafka.strimzi.io/v1alpha1","kind":"KafkaConnector","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"strimzi.io/cluster":"my-connect-cluster"},"name":"inventory-connector","namespace":"kafka"},"spec":{"class":"io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector","config":{"database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers":"my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092","database.history.kafka.topic":"schema-changes.inventory","database.hostname":"192.168.49.2","database.password":"","database.port":"3306","database.server.id":"184054","database.server.name":"dbserver1","database.user":"","database.whitelist":"inventory","include.schema.changes":"true"},"tasksMax":1}}
  creationTimestamp: "2021-09-29T18:20:11Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: my-connect-cluster
  name: inventory-connector
  namespace: kafka
  resourceVersion: "12777"
  uid: 083df9a3-83ce-4170-a9bc-9573dafdb286
spec:
  class: io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector
  config:
    database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers: my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092
    database.history.kafka.topic: schema-changes.inventory
    database.hostname: 192.168.49.2
    database.password: ""
    database.port: "3306"
    database.server.id: "184054"
    database.server.name: dbserver1
    database.user: ""
    database.whitelist: inventory
    include.schema.changes: "true"
  tasksMax: 1
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2021-09-29T18:20:11.548Z"
    message: |-
      PUT /connectors/inventory-connector/config returned 400 (Bad Request): Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):
      A value is required
      You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate`
    reason: ConnectRestException
    status: "True"
    type: NotReady
  observedGeneration: 1
```

I tried to change

```
database.user: "${file:/opt/kafka/external-configuration/connector-config/debezium-mysql-credentials.properties:mysql_username}"
database.password: "${file:/opt/kafka/external-configuration/connector-config/debezium-mysql-credentials.properties:mysql_password}"
```

to

```
database.user: "debezium"
database.password: "dbz"
```

directly and re-apply, based on the user and password info in "Secure the database credentials" step.

Also, based on the description in the tutorial

> I’m using `database.hostname: 192.168.99.1` as IP address for connecting to MySQL because I’m using minikube with the virtualbox VM driver If you’re using a different VM driver with `minikube` you might need a different IP address.

I am actually a little confused for above description. MySQL in the demo is deployed in Docker, while the rest of parts like Kafka are deployed in minikube. Why the description about `database.hostname` says minikube instead of Docker?

Anyway, when I run `minikube ip`, I got `192.168.49.2`. However, after I change `database.hostname` to `192.168.49.2`, and run `kubectl get kctr inventory-connector -o yaml -n kafka`, I got

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1alpha1
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"kafka.strimzi.io/v1alpha1","kind":"KafkaConnector","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"strimzi.io/cluster":"my-connect-cluster"},"name":"inventory-connector","namespace":"kafka"},"spec":{"class":"io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector","config":{"database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers":"my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092","database.history.kafka.topic":"schema-changes.inventory","database.hostname":"192.168.49.2","database.password":"","database.port":"3306","database.server.id":"184054","database.server.name":"dbserver1","database.user":"","database.whitelist":"inventory","include.schema.changes":"true"},"tasksMax":1}}
  creationTimestamp: "2021-09-29T18:20:11Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: my-connect-cluster
  name: inventory-connector
  namespace: kafka
  resourceVersion: "12777"
  uid: 083df9a3-83ce-4170-a9bc-9573dafdb286
spec:
  class: io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector
  config:
    database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers: my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092
    database.history.kafka.topic: schema-changes.inventory
    database.hostname: 192.168.49.2
    database.password: ""
    database.port: "3306"
    database.server.id: "184054"
    database.server.name: dbserver1
    database.user: ""
    database.whitelist: inventory
    include.schema.changes: "true"
  tasksMax: 1
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2021-09-29T18:20:11.548Z"
    message: |-
      PUT /connectors/inventory-connector/config returned 400 (Bad Request): Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):
      A value is required
      You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate`
    reason: ConnectRestException
    status: "True"
    type: NotReady
  observedGeneration: 1
```

I can access MySQL by `localhost` as it is hosted in Docker.
However, I still same error when I changed `database.hostname` to `localhost`.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: The error seems to be 400 Bad Request, so it might have connected to the host, but your input was perhaps invalid. Can you try validating your configs?

Comment: Does using double quotes "" in database hostname and other fields help?

Comment: Thanks @JavaTechnical after adding quote like `database.hostname: "192.168.49.2"`, still same.

Comment: Did you add "" for all? Also try adding `connector.class` to config and check

Comment: @JavaTechnical hmm what do you mean? In spec -> config, only `database.hostname` value does not have `""`.

Comment: Others also do not have, `database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers`,`database.history.kafka.topic`,  `database.server.name`, `database.whitelist`. Also check these required props: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-required-connector-configuration-properties

Comment: @JavaTechnical oh, when I run `kubectl apply` (written in my question), I do have `""` for all fields now (also added `""` for `database.hostname` value). However, after running `kubectl -n kafka get kctr inventory-connector -o yaml`, they just disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related with the service in minikube failed to communicate with the MySQL in the docker.

Regarding how to access host's `localhost` from inside Kubernetes cluster, I found [How to access host's localhost from inside kubernetes cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65123401/how-to-access-hosts-localhost-from-inside-kubernetes-cluster)

However, I end up with deploying MySQL in Kubernetes direction by

```
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/application/mysql/mysql-pv.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/application/mysql/mysql-deployment.yaml
```

(Copied from https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/)

with

```
database.hostname: "mysql.default" # service `mysql` in namespace `default`
database.port: "3306"
database.user: "root"
database.password: "password"
```

Now when I run

```
kubectl -n kafka get kctr inventory-connector -o yaml
```

I got a new error saying MySQL not enabling row-level binlog, however, it means it can connect the MySQL now.

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1alpha1
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"kafka.strimzi.io/v1alpha1","kind":"KafkaConnector","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"strimzi.io/cluster":"my-connect-cluster"},"name":"inventory-connector","namespace":"kafka"},"spec":{"class":"io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector","config":{"database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers":"my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092","database.history.kafka.topic":"schema-changes.inventory","database.hostname":"mysql.default","database.password":"password","database.port":"3306","database.server.id":"184054","database.server.name":"dbserver1","database.user":"root","database.whitelist":"inventory","include.schema.changes":"true"},"tasksMax":1}}
  creationTimestamp: "2021-09-29T19:36:52Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: my-connect-cluster
  name: inventory-connector
  namespace: kafka
  resourceVersion: "2918"
  uid: 48bb46e1-42bb-4574-a3dc-221ae7d6a803
spec:
  class: io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector
  config:
    database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers: my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092
    database.history.kafka.topic: schema-changes.inventory
    database.hostname: mysql.default
    database.password: password
    database.port: "3306"
    database.server.id: "184054"
    database.server.name: dbserver1
    database.user: root
    database.whitelist: inventory
    include.schema.changes: "true"
  tasksMax: 1
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2021-09-29T19:36:53.605Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  connectorStatus:
    connector:
      state: UNASSIGNED
      worker_id: 172.17.0.8:8083
    name: inventory-connector
    tasks:
    - id: 0
      state: FAILED
      trace: "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: The MySQL server is
        not configured to use a row-level binlog, which is required for this connector
        to work properly. Change the MySQL configuration to use a row-level binlog
        and restart the connector.\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask.start(MySqlConnectorTask.java:207)\n\tat
        io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.start(BaseSourceTask.java:49)\n\tat
        org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:208)\n\tat
        org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)\n\tat
        org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)\n\tat
        java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n\tat
        java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n"
      worker_id: 172.17.0.8:8083
    type: source
  observedGeneration: 1
```

Comment: Recommend you move your database password to k8s secrets

Comment: Thanks for reminding @OneCricketeer !  It is just a demo copied from https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/