# Accessing elastic search running on the host machine from a kind pod

Tags: kubernetes, service, kind

I have elasticsearch running on my host machine on port 9200.  Now I'm trying to access this from a pod running on a `kind` cluster.  This is how I have defined my external elasticsearch service.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: elasticlocal
spec:
    ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 9200
          targetPort: 9200
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
    name: elasticlocal
subsets:
    - addresses:
        - ip: 172.17.0.5
      ports:
        - port: 9200
---
```

Now when I ssh into a pod and try `curl elasticlocal:9200` I get an error saying

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.96.161.128 port 9200 after 0 ms: Connection refused`.

I am not sure if `172.17.0.5` is correct however when I inspect the docker networks on my localhost I see the following
[image]

When I inspect the kind bridge I see the following (I am using the `chatt` cluster)

[image]

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but not sure what it is

Comment: What kind of cluster do you use? Minikube, kubeadm or managed by cloud GKE, AKS, EKS? Which version of Kubernetes do you use? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65123401/how-to-access-hosts-localhost-from-inside-kubernetes-cluster) was a similar issue.

Comment: I use `Kind` cluster on my local desktop.